# Short form of "The person, who is in front of me, is Jacky."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

How can I shorten the sentence:

> "The person, who is in front of me, is Jacky."

Not only to introduce but also as opponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use gestures to indicate the location of Jacky (who is in front of the other person [you]) and say:

> "This is Jacky." or
>
> "My opponent, Jacky." or
>
> "Here is Jacky, my opponent."

Don't forget that gesture is a form of communication (nonverbal).

If you want to introduce Jacky in writing, (i.e., some sort of a journal entry), I think what you provided above is okay. There are other ways to construct the sentence though ('shorter'). (refer to Khan's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can just say "This is Jacky."

Comment: What about the person beside you? Cannot you say "This is Jackey".

Comment: If it is not meaning of introduction then ?

Comment: Or, "That person is Jacky." Or, "That's Jacky." @Devfrnd - If you're wanting to ask about introductions, you should provide more [details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) in your question.

Comment: Not only to introduce but also as opponent.

Answer (score 0):

> The person in front of me is Jacky.

You can also say:

> The person before me is Jacky.